# I want to loft/bridge through a series of different profiles to produce a car shape but cannot select all the profiles

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create a 3d object with cross sections in the xy plane which vary along the z-axis.
As a simple starter (I am unfamiliar with loop tools) I have created three mesh circles at z=0,1, 2.
What is the order of selection for generating a lofted figure?

Comment: Hello :). Your question title says: "cannot select all the profiles". Why is that not possible in your situation?

Answer (score 1):

The order of selection doesn't seem to matter.
Loops are connected based on their distance.

Selecting the loops individually, or using *Select > All* doesn't matter.

[image]

Comment: Hi I have constructed the circles using mesh/circle . When in edit mode Ican select a single circle which shows up with the vertices clearly defined in orange. When I select ALL, the first circle retains its vertices but no vertices are shown on the remaining circles, although they change colour, but to a darker shade of orange. This seems to be the main stumbling block Why is this? I am using v 2.76

Comment: Hey :). Are all your vertices joined into a single object? They need to be for this to work.

Comment: Ok I reloaded the program and started again.I took note of the single object issue,In the old model, the three circles had one vertex at the first circle at z=0.

Comment: but only one circle had  vertices in  edit mode.Now with the latest attempt, I found the join button and eventually joined all three circles. I couldn't get a result with loft, but when I tried Bridge it produced faces but only between circles 2 & 3.I now have an indicator as to what I should be  doing.:)